# set a Python program to expire after a certain number of days

Tags: python

Say I wanted to implement a 30-day trial or run a 5-day beta test. How would I go about this using Python? The idea is that the program stops working and prints a message to the user that the program has expired after said amount of time. I thought about doing it this way.

```
import sys
import time
start = time.time
expire = start + 2592000
while True:
    Run Program
    if time.time > start + expire:
        sys.exit("This program has now expired")
```

The problem with this is that the program would have to be constantly running on the user's machine for the specified amount of time. There must be a simpler or more sensible way to go about it, like having the program check at startup if a certain number of days has been reached. Thanks in advance for your input on this.

Update

I just thought of another way of doing this. Would this work?

```
import datetime
import sys

start = datetime.datetime.now()
expire = start.month + 1
while True:
    Run Program
    if datetime.datetime.now().month == expire:
        sys.exit("Your 1 month trial has expired.")
```

Comment: One way of doing this is to query your server for the expiry time and check if the current time is greater. If so, shut down the program.

Comment: If you want it to be secure as well I would suggest saving timestamp of when user started using program as well as his registered email or some id for his machine (so he can't just uninstall and install again for another trial) to your own server.

Comment: Are you bundling your python code into a binary? It's pretty hard to achieve this is in a secure way in python. If you don't hide source code, the user (for example) can disable such a check in the source.

Answer (score 2):

If you dont care about security, create a file containing the date of the first run, for example:

```
import datetime
import sys

import os


first_launch_date_filepath = ".first_launch_date"


def is_program_expired():
# Query date of first lauch in given file
    if os.path.exists(first_launch_date_filepath):
        with open(first_launch_date_filepath, 'r') as fileRead:
            time_as_str = fileRead.read()
            start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_as_str, "%Y_%m_%d")
            # Check if current time is greater than time limit
            expire_date = start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=31)
            if datetime.datetime.now() > expire_date:
                sys.exit("Your 1 month trial has expired.")
    # Supposedly first run
    else:
        start_date = datetime.datetime.now()
        with open(first_launch_date_filepath, 'w') as fileWrite:
            fileWrite.write(start_date.strftime("%Y_%m_%d"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    is_program_expired()
    # YOUR PROGRAM
```

Be carefull : **this is very insecure**, I suggest you hide that file but anyone could open this python code and figure out how to bypass this security by editing this code or the file containing the start time.

Encrypt your file, hide it, change its name.
Best way would be to use a server to store that date, upon activation, you would send the date to the server. Because this is python, any user could read, understand and modify these lines of codes to automaticaly bypass your security.

Comment: To circumvent this measure the user would simply need to remove the file.

Comment: How would this be used to specify a time limit and print an error if the user tries to run the code after the limited amount of time?

Comment: @FeelingCeiling compute the launch date with `time` in the second code block and dump it into the file, in the first code block, check in the file the date of first launch and compare it with current time.

Comment: My knowledge of time-based modules is quit limited so a code example would be helpful.